# How to align a Jumbotron with a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the Jumbotron with my form?

This example shows my form and how it is off alignment with the form:

```
<div class="jumbotron">                
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="re-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot for clarification:
[image: Screenshot of my website]
[here is my screenshot using bootstrap4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWEy1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bootstrap v3.3.7* `col` uses `float: left` In contrast, *Bootstrap v4* `col` which uses `Flexbox`.

So I guess that you are using v3.3.7 which needs `clear: both` to clear the float effect, this is already built-in inside bootstrap css **BUT** you have to use `.row` before `col` becuse `.row` the one who has the clear property.

Finally you just have to add `<div class="row">` and it will solve your issue.

Check the following [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/pdOR7ciMNS#).

**Update**

There is also another solution which is `.clearfix`,

Place `<div class="clearfix"></div>` **Directly** after `.col-md-6` and it will also clear the float.

Check updated [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/j2EArif2TJ) using `.clearfix`.

If you are exhausted and want to know more abot *Floats and Clear*,

You may check this [Article](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) it will help you.

Comment: i am new to this and am slightly overwhelmed by your answer but the solution works. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer for another option you could use, and if my answer solved your problem you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me. You either need to update your bootstrap version. I used bootstrap 4.0.0. Or perhaps the problem here is with your browser. Try to update your browser to the latest version.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">                
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                      <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                      <input id="re-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: i tried your solution and added a link using bootstrap 4. i think my browsers are updated to the newest version

Comment: What 's your browser version ?

Comment: chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
everything seems to contract as i make my window larger

Comment: the problem not the browser nor bootstrap version, check out my answer